# How to skip N rows in QuestDB SQL?

Tags: questdb

I'm creating paging output from data in QuestDB table and want to take 100 rows after X pages of 100 rows. In Postgres it would be something like

```
select * from tbl
OFFSET 200
LIMIT 100
```

I see `LIMIT` but cannot find `OFFSET` equivalent in QuestDB SQL, is it supported?

Comment: Actually yes, thanks, I should have looked at LIMIT to find OFFSET

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @basha04 the equivalent query is

```
select * from tbl
LIMIT 200,300
```